# Javascript EventListener and Element Selector problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, jquery-selectors

Long story short, I have a JavaScript selector issue.

I have a loop that creates several elements, which each have the same button and a different input value.
Clicking a button needs to increase the associated input value by 1, and change aspect (toggle between +1 and -1).

My problem is that clicking on one button changes the aspect of all of them, and increases the value of the last input value instead of it's associated one.

I've tried using [i] with the selector, as well as getElementsByNames instead and many more.

Doesn't seem easy to explain clearly, this might help :
https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/qBaZNbb

Thanks for any help you can give.

HTML :

```
     <div class="photoGrid">  </div>
```

Javascipt:

```
const PhotographeID= 82; 
var jsonFile =  {
        "media": [
    { "photographerId": 82, "likes": 82, },
    { "photographerId": 82, "likes": 62, }
]}
  
const photoLikes= document.getElementById ('photoLikes');
var photoGrid  = document.getElementsByClassName('photoGrid')[0];
var heart=  document.getElementById('heart');
var imageCard  = document.getElementsByClassName('imageCard')[0];

function findId(jsonFile, idToLookFor) {
var media = jsonFile.media;
for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
if (media[i].photographerId == idToLookFor) {
          
// Creating Dom Elements
 var imageCard = document.createElement('div');
 imageCard.classList.add('imageCard');
 photoGrid.appendChild(imageCard);
                
 var photoInfos = document.createElement('div');
 photoInfos.classList.add('photoInfos');
 imageCard.appendChild(photoInfos);   
                       
 var photoLikes = document.createElement('input');
 photoLikes.classList.add('photoLikes');
 photoLikes.setAttribute("type", "number");
 photoLikes.setAttribute("value", media[i].likes);
 photoLikes.readOnly = true;
 photoInfos.appendChild(photoLikes);        
          
 var heart = document.createElement('span');
 heart.classList.add('heart');
  heart.classList.add(i);
 photoInfos.appendChild(heart);   
          
  var faHeart= document.createElement('i');
  faHeart.classList.add('fa');
  faHeart.classList.add('fa-heart-o');
  faHeart.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true" );
  faHeart.setAttribute("id", "faHeart");
  heart.appendChild(faHeart);
  
  
// like button functions 
var heartI= document.getElementsByClassName(i);
  
heart.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
if( heart.classList.contains("liked")){
$(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
heart.classList.remove("liked");
      
 /*Removes 1 like */
 var value = parseInt(photoLikes.value, 10);
 value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
 value--;
 photoLikes.value = value;  
    }
  
  else{
      $(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      heart.classList.add("liked");
    
    /*adds 1 like */
var value = parseInt(photoLikes.value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
photoLikes.value = value; 
    }
  });
; } } }
findId(jsonFile, PhotographeID);
```

Comment: don't use var if you dont explicitly need it's behaviour. JS "teleports" a var declaration to the top of the function body. That can behave strange at some cases if you don't know about that. Use const or let instead. Using photolikes as a const outside the function, as a local var inside the function and as a upperscoped vaiable inside the eventlistener arrow function might not be a good idea too. Have you proved, it is always the "linked" photolikes.value your are in-/decreasing?

Comment: I'm going through my code and your answer. Indeed changing "var photolikes" to "const photolikes" has solved the +1 -1 problem! Thank you soooo much I was starting to loose hope. i'll finish applying your advice mabye it will solve the other issue  too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooo, I got every thing working: https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/qBaZNbb?editors=1010

1. As pointed out by @kaiLehmann the counting problem was due to misusage of Var instead of Const.
2. The aspect of the buttons changing together was due to the usage of :

`$(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>');`

instead of
`heart.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>';`

I don't know exactly why though, if anyone could explain the difference, expect that one is plain JS and the other Jquery, that would be great!

Comment: Bravo having solved this yourself! About your remaining questionning: `heart` is a variable you used to create a `span` element... So it refers to that element only during a `for` loop iteration. --- And `$(".heart")` is the collection of all elements in the page having the `hearth` class at the time of the lookup. Now, the method applied (`.html()`) can only apply to one element... So jQuery assumes it is the first of the collection.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks a lot. If I understand correctly, the problem was within the ````.html()```` and not the ````$(".heart")```` selector which i didn't need to change?

Comment: No, the issue was with the `$(".heart")` being a collection (read: a list) of all the elements having the `heart` class... From that list of element, `.html()` was applied on the first only. In your for loop, `$(".heart").last()` would have worked, but using the JS `heart` variable is better.